# From API to vector layer openlayers JSON

Tags: json, maps, openlayers

If you want to import a json file in your system to a vector layer, is as easy as:

```
    var restaurantsold = new ol.layer.Vector({
    title: 'b_layer',
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        url: 'restaurantjson.geojson',

        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
    }),
});
```

And I can add that layer directly to the map. But if I try to make a call to an API, I can't display it in the map, my best try has been this:

```
var restaurants;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://tour-pedia.org/api/getPlaces?category=restaurant&location=Berlin&name=La+Dolce+Vita",
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data)
            restaurants = data;
            $(restaurants).each(function(index, value) {

                console.log(value.address);
            });
            }
    });
    var resta2 = new ol.layer.Vector({
        title : "Resta2",
        source: new ol.source.Vector(restaurants)
    });
```

And I can't find a proper solution anywhere for this, thanks for your help!

EDIT:
at the end the problem was that it gets a JSON file, and openlayers wants an GeoJSON file.. my way to solve it was to convert it to GeoJSON following this: 
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73756/is-it-possible-to-convert-regular-json-to-geojson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Restaurant data might not be available at all when you are creating the vector layer since you are making an Ajax Call.

So convert the GeoJSON to collection of `ol.Feature` objects using `ol.format.GeoJSON` `readFeatures()` method. Then add it vector source using `addFeatures()` method.

**Fix :**

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
    })

 var restaurantsold = new ol.layer.Vector({
    title: 'b_layer',
    source : vectorSource
});

 $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://tour-pedia.org/api/getPlaces?category=restaurant&location=Berlin&name=La+Dolce+Vita",
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(data){
            // If response is valid
            var geojsonFormat = new ol.format.GeoJSON();

            // reads and converts GeoJSon to Feature Object
            var features = geojsonFormat.readFeatures(data);
            vectorSource.addFeatures(features);
        }
    });
```

Comment: You are right! I completely forgot to do my try inside a callback, buuut, your solution does not work either :( Console does not show any error, is there something I can do to try to track errors?

Comment: Check the data returned from AJAX call. The data should be in GeoJSON format or Data might contain some object which contains GeoJSON response.

Comment: I had a console log displaying the results in my first code, the structure is Array [ Object, Object, Object ], and each object has the properties like name, lat, lng, id... looks pretty geoJson for me.

Comment: I have applied this solution bet layer not shown in the map!